# Cannot push git error: hook declined with remote ruby error

Tags: ruby, git, githooks

One day, I suddenly just cannot push to one of res (While pulling is fine). This is the error log

```
Writing objects: 100% (42/42), 11.23 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 42 (delta 34), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:2:in `require':
 no such file to load-- rubygems (LoadError)
remote:         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:2
remote:         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:1:in `require'
remote:         from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:1
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
To http://192.168.1.140:8000/chnn/application2.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://192.168.1.140:8000/chnn/application2.git'
```

I can also create a new project and push it to gitlab just fine. Only 1 project has this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. So in my particular case, no problem is found within the server. We were desperate and tried to push over ssh rather than http and then bam, it works again.
In the end, we do not know why and how. The question still remains:

- Why we can push normally over http if create new projects
- Why other
  do not have this problem

Answer (score 2):

Ask your git repo admin with this error. It is custom git hook (mean git plugin) crash.

Comment: I have a co-worker and he can push it normally. If it is a server problem, how can he do that?